# Adobe LiveCycle Designer Check Box Values not being saved when using Automation

Tags: pdf, automation, adobe, pdf-generation, livecycle

I'm using Automation to populate and save a set of Adobe LiveCycle created forms from a database.

For testing, I have the form visible while populating it and can see the checkbox values being properly set.  But when saving the form, everything *EXCEPT* the checkboxes/radiobuttons settings are being saved with the form.

I can manually open one of the forms and set various checkbox values and save the form, and they retain their settings.

Does anyone know how to get LiveCycle Designer checkbox values to retain their values on Save when using Automation?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the form defines a selected check box in the same way the data does. For example, if the checked-value in the form is '1', and the checked-value in the data is 'Yes', you will get problems.